# trying to change background colour for a tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def button_click():
    print("Button clicked")

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Calculator")
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(bg="#8cb3b8", bd=10)
window.resizable(0, 0)

num_one = Button(text="1", command=button_click,width=2, height=2,bg='green',highlightbackground="#8cb3b8", highlightcolor="#8cb3b8")
num_one.place(x=2,y=100)

window.mainloop()
```

> unable to change the background colour for this project. Tried using configure function and still not successful, is there any other ways that might work.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.16.  Is your platform MacOS? If yes, try using module [`tkmacosx`](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/).

Comment: @acw1668 I will give it a go, I am on MacOS maybe that could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing it using the background property.

```
window['background']='#8cb3b8'
```

Comment: According to the title of the question, OP wants to change the background color of a button, not the window. OP has already tried it, but don't know why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of the window in your tkinter code, you can modify the bg attribute of the window object. Here's an updated version of your code with a different background color:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def button_click():
    print("Button clicked")

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Calculator")
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(bg="#ff0000", bd=10)  # Change the background color 
here
window.resizable(0, 0)

num_one = Button(text="1", command=button_click, width=2, height=2, 
bg='green', highlightbackground="#ff0000", highlightcolor="#ff0000")
num_one.place(x=2, y=100)

window.mainloop()
```

In the code above, I changed the background color to #ff0000, which represents red. You can modify the color by providing a different hexadecimal color code.

On google you can go to this link to choose your colour and replace the # with the hex code.
https://www.google.com/search?q=google+color+picker&oq=google+color+picker&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQRRhA0gEIMjk5NmowajeoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on#cobssid=s

Comment: According to the title of the question, OP wants to change the background color of a button, not the window. OP has already tried it, but don't know why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def button_click():
    print("Button clicked")
    window.configure(bg='red')
```